# window.focus() not working inside event listener

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, event-listener

I have a child window open and I want to focus it when certain event is received on my parent window. I have the reference to my child window however window.focus() is not firing when it is called from message event listener, however on click of button from parent window it is working fine. Below is the piece of code for reference

```
useEffect(() => {
  const onMessageLoad = async (message) => {
    if (typeof message.data !== "object" && message.data !== "") {
      if (eventReceived === true) {
        const childWindow = (window as any)?.childWindow;
        if (childWindow === undefined) {
          console.log("child window is not opened");
        } else {
          console.log("child window is opened");
          childWindow.focus(); // ---> this is not working
        }
      }
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("message", onMessageLoad);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("message", onMessageLoad);
  };
}, []);
```

1. I tried blurring window and focusing it again.
2. Maintained a state with boolean flag and then invoke the focus func

Comment: Are you sure you're getting into `childWindow.focus();` part?

Comment: Also if you could provide some context about your development environment (like if its local server or code sandbox in browser)

Comment: Yes I have the reference to childWindow! It running on local react server

Comment: I tried to replicate that on code sandbox, and it seems to be working, at least for me, here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-dhawan-p3tpfq, you may find something that will help you. Otherwise it may be something with your OS / permissions.